# How do I create an installer for a java Application using exe4j?

Tags: java, exe

When I create an installer using `exe4j`, I'm getting these errors:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: credit/home : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

What am I suppose to do to fix these errors? Is this my Netbeans Project Error?

Comment: The version of Java you're using to run the program is earlier then the one you created the application with (ie compiled with Java 8, run with Java 7)

Comment: but  my java version is 1.8 ,  sir can you explain what i m suppose to do?

Comment: Make sure that the `java_home` environment variable is pointing to a Java 8 installation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project,goto properties and see whether java compiler version and java build path both are using same java version.

Comment: my java version is jdk 1.8.  sir can you explain what i m suppose to do?

Comment: add jdk package to your build path by browsing to target jdk location in your file system and goto java compiler tab can be found in properties of your project and select compiler version to 1.8 which is your jdk version.

Comment: ok i ll do it. anyway i have another question, can add mysql database to exe4j ?

Comment: yes u can,add jar appropriate to mysql database you can find them easily just google it